# What is the difference between Dplay.server.netty.maxHeaderSize vs Dhttp.netty.maxHeaderSize?

Tags: playframework

I tried looking this up in playframework official documentation and but don't see it mentioned anywhere. Would appreciate if anyone knows the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In play2.4x, maxHeaderSize could be set and read as [environment variable](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.x/framework/src/play-netty-server/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L17) but this in not the case in [play2.5x](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play-netty-server/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L19). So if your app is running on play2.5, you should use Dplay.server.netty.maxHeaderSize